# proper method of constructing subject lines with special characters and tokens in SendGrid

Tags: java, sendgrid

I am using Java SendGrid API to send emails with subject lines in en, ja and ko characters and the subject linea contains a substitution token. It works fine for most cases but some ja and ko subject lines get broken within the token part so the substitution is not working. For workaround, I put line breaks after each space in the subject line. However, this approach does not work when the subject is pure English text. The xsmtpapi header seems not generated properly so no xsmtpapi-related fields get updated.

Has anyone encountered a similar case? Are there any best practices or guidelines for constructing subject lines considering special characters and tokens?

Here is a sample code to send the email:

Hi ouflak,

Here is the sample code:

`SendGrid sendGrid = new SendGrid(<sendgridusername>,<sendgridpassword>);
    sendGrid.setFrom("xxx@xxxxx.com");
    sendGrid.setTo("yyy@yyyyy.com");
    ...
    sendGrid.setSubject("sample subject line");
    sendGrid.addHeader("X-SMTPAPI", <generated xsmtpapi header>);
    String response = sendGrid.send();`

Comment: Could we see your code?

Comment: Hi @ouflak, had updated the details above for the sample code.